# Image not scaling in table within Outlook 2007

Tags: html-email, outlook-2007

I have an image that is acting as a header.  It scales fine if it's outside of a table.  As soon as I drop it in a table, the image stops scaling.

I've tried various things such as setting the image width to 100%, leaving the image width and height undefined, setting the actual dimensions (660 x 248) and then setting the table width to 100%, using three table cells and setting the width of the center table cell with the image, etc...

I am using straight HTML and not using CSS.

No matter what I try, the image will not scale down if it's in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, my guess is it is simply that the table is a declared value, so then even though the image is relative, it is relative to a defined value.  Meaning that your image does not scale since the table wrapper never scales because it always stays at the declared value you put it to.

Other issue could be since Outlook 2007 does not usually like percentage declaration on images, it will define it as the initial load value or the value of the metadata on the image itself. This removes all scaling capabilities. Best bet to help on this issue is provided by [Litmus](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/151-mystery-solved-dpi-scaling-in-outlook-2007-2013)

Comment: I tried what was recommended in Litmus and it still won't scale the image correctly.  The issue isn't with scaling the image up, but rather scaling it down when the viewing pane is displaying the content.  The image remains at the original size even when declaring width/height on the image, the table, and all cells, along with including the helper classes from Litmus.

Comment: Does the table scale without the image? Without seeing any code or having more info it is hard to diagnose.  I would still say it is likely something between outlook and your code. Have you tried it on other clients with any success?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting a fixed width and height where ever possible?

```
<table width="660" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="660" height="248" ><img src="images/image.jpg" style="display:block;" width="660" height="248" border="0" alt=""/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Also, is the image that full 660 x 248 or is it being stretched?

Comment: I just tried that and still have not had any luck.  I declared width and height on the cell containing the image along with width and height on the image, as well.  I also declared width on the table, itself.  The image is 660 x 248 without being stretched.